# Setting default parameters in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a way to set a default numerical value to my defaults parameters of my plugin or have the option to retrieve the default value via an ajax call. In other words:

```
  var defaults = {
        param1: 1000,
        totalTime : null // the default value i'm looking for in seconds
    }
```

So that:

```
$('.test').myPlugin({
    param1: 1000,
    totalTime: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'totaltime.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                // retrieve value here
            }
        });         

    }
});

OR 

$('.test').myPlugin({
    param1: 1000,
    totalTime: 200 // numerical
});
```

I only recently started playing with plugins and found this an interesting concept but am having a little trouble with it. Here's what my plugin looks like now (the basic set up for new plugin).

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        var plugin = this;

        var defaults = {
            param1: 1000,
            totalTime : null
        }

        plugin.init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            plugin.timer();
        }   

        plugin.settings = {}

        plugin.timer = function() {

        }

        plugin.init();
        return this;

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just define your defaults like this:

```
var defaults =$.extend( {
        param1: 1000,
        totalTime : null
    },options);
```

and then you can use it like `defaults.param1` or `defaults.totalTime`

UPDATE:

the above example is how you can set the totalTime value numerically as default.

if you wanna change it during your plugin then you can do this:

```
defaults.totalTime=500;
```

or

```
defaults.totalTime=givenVal; //givenVal is a variable that contains the value
```

also in your jQuery code, you can set the totalTime as this:

```
$('#test').myPlugin({
    totalTime:500
});
```

or

```
$('#test').myPlugin({
    totalTime:givenVal
});
```

so now all you should do is to get the value from ajax, put it in a variable, and pass it to your plugin as mentioned above!

Comment: But how does this allow me to use an ajax function get my wanted value versus just putting a simply value for totalTime?

Comment: you mean you wanna get the value of totalTime from ajax and then use it on an element? if yes, is the ajax call inside your plugin or outside?

Comment: I want to get the totalTime value via ajax and use it to do calculate something in my plugin. I want to either put the value numerically or get the value via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

@AminJafari has indicated how to correctly define your defaults. Below is how to call your plugin with a value from an ajax request. **NOTE: the `totalTime callback` has to return a value, and the value has to be available to be returned.** -- which means it's got to be done in the `success` callback of the ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'totaltime.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('.test').myPlugin({
                param1: 1000,
                totalTime: function () {
                    // retrieve value here
                    return data.timeValue; //for example
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: So there's no way to assign the value from ajax without wrapping my entire plugin in $.ajax ?

Comment: You could make your request `synchronous` but that means you've taken the `A` out of `AJAX` = SJAX. Just note that synchronous request freeze your browser until the request is completed.